# Are there any grains that do not become chometz?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, passover

Are there any grains or grainlike produce (not kitnios) that cannot become chometz?

Comment: I had always thought that the ideal matzo would be made from a grain that does not become chometz. But the truth is otherwise. Matzo can only be made from the five species of grain that can become chometz. There has to be a challenge!

Comment: Not about matza making just about foods permitted on pesach. For the person who downvoted can you explain why you think this question is invalid?

Comment: Chamezt applies ONLY to the 5 grains - wheat barley, rye oats and spelt. Any other grain does not become chametz. You can pick any you like - rice, buckwheat, corn, quinoa, etc.

Comment: @Laser123 Downvotes don't mean the question is invalid. They mean it's poor. Try editing in what you mean by grain or grainlike, for instance, or why you suspect such a food exists. It seems likely anything grainlike is kitbiyot by definition

Comment: my comment was deleted for what reason? Quinoa is grain like and not kitnios and beans are kitnios but not grain like. The definition of kitnios is not grain like.

Answer (score 1):

Echoing NoachMiFrankfurt's answer of Quinoa, the grain-like food isn't kitnios and doesn't become chametz. In an article by the Star-K titled "Quinoa: The Grain That's Not" Rabbi Rosen [writes](http://www.star-k.org/articles/articles/seasonal/363/quinoa-the-grain-thats-not/),

> Quinoa was determined to be Kosher L’Pesach. It is not related to the
>   chameishes minei dagan-five types of grain products, nor to millet or
>   rice. Quinoa is a member of the “goose foot” family, which includes
>   sugar beets and beet root. The Star-K tested quinoa to see if it would
>   rise. The result was as Chazal termed, sirchon; the quinoa decayed –
>   it did not rise.